# How can i know if user delete my app from device and reinstall it again on the same device without user registeration

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app in which users can use some data without registration and data limited. how can I know if the user uninstalls my app and reinstall it again on the same device?

I tried to use a UUID package to sign a device but it does not work.

EDIT: I figure out an idea to get device id and store it on web when the user uninstall app and reinstall again i will know user old usage